exception: failed to open or create the database while running on my flutter application to android phone in debugging mode
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:landproject/models/sdata.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';

class DbService {
  DbService() {
    sqfliteFfiInit();
    databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  }

  Database? _database;

  Future<Database> getDatabase() async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    try {
  _database = await openDatabase(
    join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'my_database.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
        '''CREATE TABLE mamla(
           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
           description TEXT NOT NULL
        )'''
      );
    },
    version: 1,
  );
} catch (e) {
  print("Exception occurred: $e");
  rethrow;  
}

    return _database!;
  }

  Future<int> createData(Sdata sd) async {
    final db = await getDatabase();
    return await db.insert("mamla", sd.toMap());
  }

  Future<List<Sdata>> getData() async {
    final db = await getDatabase();
    List myd = await db.query("mamla",orderBy: "id DESC");
    return myd.map(
      (mp) => Sdata.fromMap(mp)
    ).toList();
  }

  Future<List<Sdata>> getSpecificData(int id)async{
    final db=await getDatabase();
    List myd=await db.query(
      "mamla",
      where: "id=?",
      whereArgs: [id]
    );
    return myd.map((map)=> Sdata.fromMap(map)).toList();
  }
  Future<void> updateData(Sdata sd)async{
    final db=await getDatabase();
    db.update("mamla", sd.toMap(),where: "id=?",whereArgs: [sd.id]);
  }
}

this is my code of db helper. on my windows the application runs fine and the db works as well. But when i try to run this on my android phone the exception of failed to open or create database is shows up. Why this problem has arrived? and how can i fix that?
I am accessing this db . but in my android phone the exception shows up.

Adding the exception you're getting and the stack trace could help. Thanls!
